# C# How to receive information from serial port that doesn't end in "\r" or "\n"

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, newline

In my application I have a serial port object and a listbox. In the DataRecieved event, I send  serialPort.ReadLine() to the listbox. If I write a "n" character to the serial port, nothing will get added to the listbox because what gets recieved doesn't end in "\r" or "\n".

What is the correct way to read information from a serial port? (Keep in mind that I need to keep the full string/char[] of the last thing recieved.)

Comment: Are you setting the SerialPort.NewLine property based on what the device streams output?

Comment: Everything this device sends ends in "\r"... except when you send "n".

Answer (score 3):

The 'correct' way depends heavily on implementation.

The `SerialPort.ReadLine()` method expects a CR/LF as a means to define a payload unit. And, by *thing*, I imagine that you mean exactly that - a *message*, *payload* or *package* (as in one meaningful, functional unit of information.)

What `SerialPort.ReadLine()` does is to wrap the whole 'receive everything coming from the buffer and wait for a end-of-payload mark before continuing' mechanism for you.

If you'd rather have the raw incoming content as soon as it arrives, then you may consider changing your code to use [`SerialPort.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: This is pretty much it. If you want it to be asynchronous, you can `await` on `SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync()`. As mentioned, there needs to be be some kind of delimiter whether it's a new-line character, a pipe, or whatever have you.

Answer (score 1):

If your message consists of an exact amount of bytes (sometimes the case with sensor data protocols) you can define the bytes you expect - but you should set a timeout in this case.

```
SerialPort.ReadTimeout = timeOut;
SerialPort.Read(responseBytes, 0, bytesExpected)
```

Comment: +1 - that's a nifty thing to keep in mind when dealing with sensors.